# Win32 newbie: Firefox-like find bar

Tags: winapi, dialog, find

Firefox has this nice find-a-text-on-the-page dialog, which is non-modal and shows up at the bottom of the window. How to do something similar using just Win32? I guess there has to edit control but do I have to position it manually on parent window WM_SIZE? How do I dismiss the dialog, i.e. how to make it disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, use a rebar and put an edit control and the buttons that you need on it. You'll have to manage all the rest yourself, manually (close button, showing/hiding it, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is what you call a rebar...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774373(VS.85).aspx. Google if you need more info...